# Explaining The Evolution of a Bioengineering Species

Tags: xenobiology, parasites

**Re: Ultimate Alien Parasite**

It's been well established that parasites can alter their hosts. Gall wasps, for example, use viral  or bacterial vectors to make a plant form galls around their young. Furthermore, genes can be transferred between species by viral and bacterial vectors. And, to top it all off, [cells can fuse into hybrid cells](https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn4558-pig-human-chimeras-contain-cell-surprise/) and cells are capable of collective behavior (as evidenced by [cellular slime mold](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/immunology-and-microbiology/cellular-slime-mold)).

For one of the worlds I'm trying to build, a centerpiece is the aliens attacking the humans, which all exhibit some degree of biological and/or mechanical engineering. I was thinking this would best be explained by some sort of ruling class, an alien species capable of intense genetic modification, but then I have to explain them as this setting would be science-fiction and disbelief can only be suspended so far.

My question is, therefore, **What Conditions Would Lead Cells to Develop An Organism Capable of Genetically Altering its Victims?**

This alien must:

- Have enough intelligence to plan ahead, evaluate traits in light of likely scenarios, and engineer accordingly
- Be capable of extracting, storing, interpreting, and manipulating (AKA breaking and reforming) DNA in a way that makes its "host" better at fulfilling a desired function
- Be capable of acting as a cooperative unit, despite being a swarm of cells (can be evolved into complex organism, but swarm of hive-mind microorganisms would be nice)
- Be capable of controlling or at least altering the brain of a host to ensure desired behavior
- Be capable of communication (preferably soundless) between other members of its kind and those affected by them (if aliens are in a horde, they should be able to coordinate their actions through this method)

**Basically, this alien species is a hive-minded colony of cells, with intelligence about as complex as a human's, capable of genetically manipulating a creature and its brain, adapting it into a tool for its own design, and then communicating with other such "swarms" and their engineered thralls in order to coordinate their efforts. What conditions would cause this creature to evolve to manipulate its fellow wildlife and thereby become a biological overlord?**

Comment: You're asking us how your fictional creature can evolve in your fictional world? Millions of years worth of evolutionary decisions.... Please understand, the word "conditions" refers to a massive number of circumstances and consequences that range from random chance (they survived the meteor impact because...) to superior design (they outlived their competition because....). Why are you asking this question? What's your goal? How will you use the answers? Somehow you need to narrow the focus from open-endend & hypothetical to practical & specific.

Comment: You should narrow the focus of your question - currently it seems to be about biological mechanisms for genetic manipulation, possible evolutionary paths, communication, mindcontrol ... all over the place.

Comment: Are you looking for a list of evolutionary factors that facilitate the appearance of said abilities?

Comment: @Otkin: yes, that'd be great, although I worry it is too much.

Comment: @bukwyrm: no fear, now that the weekend's over, I will follow JoinJBH's advice and focus the question to see if I can reopen it. I'll start with the genetic modification ability and work from there.